Filament: How to pass "edit" status to the page?
The hide and disabled function does work when click on the edit button on the table.

However, it does not work when click on the "edit" button from the modal.

public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                TextInput::make('name')->required(),
                TextInput::make('email')->email()->required()->disabledOn('edit'),
                TextInput::make('password')->password()->required()->hiddenOn('edit'),
            ]);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('id'),
                TextColumn::make('name'),
                TextColumn::make('email'),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\ViewAction::make()
                    ->extraModalFooterActions([
                        Tables\Actions\EditAction::make()
                    ]),
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ]);
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListUsers::route('/'),
        ];
    }

How can I have the "edit" status to be passed into the form so that the hiddenOn() and disabledOn() works?
